# Interesting vs. hot questions

Tags: support, questions, hot-questions, interesting-page

Just being curious of difference between **interesting** and **hot** questions in tabs. Both of them have been answered or modified recently, but how do they differ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Interesting questions:

["Interesting" questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) - has group of questions tagged with your self-selected favorite tags.

#### Hot questions :

Hot questions determined by a formula mentioned in [this Meta SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)

```
(log(Qviews)*4) + ((Qanswers * Qscore)/5) + sum(Ascores)
--------------------------------------------------------
((QageInHours+1) - ((QageInHours - Qupdated)/2)) ^ 1.5
```